# Is there a equivalent of boost::timer::cpu_timer in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, boost

I have a always running process in C# which is idle unless it receives a request to process. Once a request is received it goes on processing that request till it finishes upon which it becomes idle again. I want to get the CPU wall time, user time and the system time for each request similar to `boost::timer::cpu_timer` in C++.

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime, 
Process.GetCurrentProcess().UserProcessorTime 
Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivilegedProcessorTime
```

would give me the times for all the requests (as its a continuous running process).

I want the times per request. Is there a way in C# we can get this?

Comment: Note that the boost class will also time the whole process, not just a single request - if there are multiple "concurrent" actions going on in your process you'll get the accumulated CPU time for them all. There is simply no such thing that could measure the CPU time based on distinct actions / requests. Whether that is boost (native) or .net (managed) code.

Comment: Thanks Christian.K. I was hoping to use in C# something similar to for each request. boost::timer::cpu_timer m_timer;
m_timer.start();
boost::timer::format(m_timer.elapsed(), boost::timer::default_places, "%w %u %s w/u/s");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all else fails, you can always just calculate the differences.

Note that this will not be accurate, because inevitably the kernel counts **all** CPU time that was alloted to the process, not just for handling a certain request.

But as long as you know that you've only served a single request during a particular time frame, using the difference between e.g. `Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime` before and after the operation could be used as a reasonable estimate.

Comment: You may want to emphasize that "that this will not be accurate" will also be the case when using boost (because the OP seemed to be concerned about that).